# How to avoid man in the middle attacks when sending sensible info via email?

Tags: email, man-in-the-middle

I'm setting up a website where users can buy cupons. I should send coupons codes to customers via email and these codes are enough to use the coupon. How can I avoid man in the middle attacks? Do you have any suggestions? I would like to avoid to send encrypted info! Thank to everybody

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mail will pass through several mail servers on its way to the user. Even if the transport between these servers is encrypted (which you as the sender cannot control and thus not guarantee) the mails are available in plain on each of the servers. Moreover the mail is available in plain on the final server where the user then will retrieve it from. Thus, plenty of ways for somebody to intercept it.

If despite this you still want to use mail you need to make sure that the contents of the mail is only useful for the intended recipient. Alternatively you could simply accept the risk that somebody might read the mail and misuse the coupons - which might be an acceptable option if the value of the coupons is low anyway.

One way to protect the coupons would be to encrypt the mail with established methods like PGP or S/MIME. Only you don't want encryption and it would be hard to to anyway since these methods are only established as protocols but are not widely used and supported in practice - so it would not work anyway with most recipients.

Another way would be to encrypt only the coupons in the mail and provide the necessary password to the user during the buying process or let the user pick a password. But, again this is encryption you don't want and the process of sharing the password with the user will probably be too complex to some users and discourage them.

You might also send only a link to the coupons in the mail and the user has to login with the same information he used to buy the coupons in order to retrieve the coupons from your website. This might be a username and password if you have user accounts anyway or it might be parts of the credit card used to buy the coupons etc.  Of course in this case it might be simpler to not send the mail in the first place but just let the user download the coupons at the moment they bought them.

Or, if you insist on using mail (which is unprotected) you might just accept the risk that someone else might get access to the coupons and add a verification later when the coupons get used. This might be done by personalizing the coupons and require some kind of validation when the coupons gets used. Depending on how they get used this might be some kind of identification of who is using the coupons or making sure that the person using the coupons has access to the same credit card which was used to buy the coupons.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I suspected there were no easy way out, since I searched a bit before posting this question. I suppose that I will keep things simple and try to give info to users in their personal page. Thanks again